# Is there a CUDA smart pointer?

Tags: memory, cuda, gpgpu, smart-pointers

If not, what is the standard way to free up `cudaMalloc`ed memory when an exception is thrown? (Note that I am unable to use Thrust.)

Comment: What would be throwing the exception?

Comment: Any function or class member - i.e. many things

Comment: I mean, will the host code be throwing exceptions in response to an error from the CUDA runtime, or are these other error conditions not related to CUDA?

Comment: @MiloChen May I ask in which cases do you need to free GPU memory after an exception? I guess it is when the exception does not abort the program, right? When does it occur in your cases?

Comment: The corresponding free operation for [cudaMalloc()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g16a37ee003fcd9374ac8e6a5d4dee29e) is [cudaFree()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g02b08ab28cfc28c37976556044fb5335)  It's also common to test that the pointer is not NULL before passing it to cudaFree, but not necessary in all cases.

Comment: You could put the `cudaFree()` calls in a cleaning function that would be called when catching the exceptions in your host code. However, the manner in which you should handle these exceptions really depends on what you are trying to achieve, and we won't be able to help you without some more details.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom and put your `cudaMalloc()` and `cudaFree()` calls to the constructor and destructor of your object respectively.

Once the exception is thrown your destructor will be called which will free the allocated memory.

If you wrap this object into a smart-pointer (or make it behave like a pointer) you will get your CUDA smart-pointer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this custom [`cuda::shared_ptr`](https://github.com/roostaiyan/CudaSharedPtr) implementation. As mentioned above, this implementation uses `std::shared_ptr` as a wrapper for CUDA device memory.

### Usage Example:

```
std::shared_ptr<T[]> data_host =  std::shared_ptr<T[]>(new T[n]);
.
.
.

// In host code:
fun::cuda::shared_ptr<T> data_dev;
data_dev->upload(data_host.get(), n);
// In .cu file:
// data_dev.data() points to device memory which contains data_host;
```

This repository is indeed a single header file ([`cudasharedptr.h`](https://github.com/roostaiyan/CudaSharedPtr/blob/main/cudasharedptr.h)), so it will be easy to manipulate it if is necessary for your application.